# cant seem to see images on node.js server

Tags: node.js, image

What it looks like when the server is running on localhost:300 :

[image: what it looks when the server is running on localhost:300]

What the HTML looks like itself:

[image: what the HTML looks like itself]

I am very new to this and trying to make a video game website for people to purchase things. I wanted to have pictures of the game so that it can make the webpage look nicer but I can't seem to see the pictures on the server. I can see them on the HTML file when opened in chrome but not on localhost. I have done a lot of research on this and can't seem to figure it out. Is there any chance I can get some help on being able to get the images to show on the server?

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<HTML>

 <style type="text/css">

/* start of nav css*/
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
color: #f00253;
padding: 20px;
}

.nav{
list-style-type: none;
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
background-color: #3f3d3d;
padding-left: 25%;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.nav li a {
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 70px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
background-color: #f00253;
}

/* finish of nav css*/


</style>

<head>
<title>Jonathan's Database Game Store</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Jonathan's Database Game Store</h1>

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PC Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Xbox Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Playstation Gmaes</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="left"> 
    <h2>Raingbow Six Seige</h2>
    <img src="r6.webp">

    

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

server.js Code

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
fs.readFile('home.html', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        res.writeHead(404)
        res.write('Error: File Not Found')
    } else {
        res.write(data)
    }
    res.end()
 })
 
})

server.listen(port, function(error){
if (error) {
    console.log('something went wrong', error)
} else {
    console.log('server is listening on port ' + port)
}

})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "see the picture on the servers"

Comment: when I go to the localhost:3000 I can see everything that I made on my page but images show that there should be an image but the image itself doesn't show. I have added pictures of it at the top of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why Mushroom idiot's previous code did not work.  was missing the __dirname + in the following code res.sendFile(__dirname + "/PC.html"). Here is the final code that works with the HTML and images.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const server = app.listen(3000, () => { // create a HTTP server on 
port 3000
console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`)
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname, { // host the whole directory
    extensions: ["html", "htm", "gif", "png"],
}))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/PC.html")
})

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
return res.sendStatus(404)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

Using NodeJS' HTTP module to make a HTTP server is pretty tedious, what the problem is, is that you aren't hosting the images on your HTTP server.

## The fix

I would recommend that you use [Express](https://npmjs.org/package/express) which makes everything way easier.

Install it with `npm i express` in console then you can use this code for your HTTP server

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const server = app.listen(3000, () => { // create a HTTP server on port 3000
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`)
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname, { // host the whole directory
        extensions: ["html", "htm", "gif", "png"],
    }))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile("./PC.html")
})

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return res.sendStatus(404)
})
```

Comment: hey, I ended up trying the code that you suggested and installed the express package that I needed but while trying to start the server I got a app.use(compression(), ^  ReferenceError: compression is not defined. I ended up looking it up and saw that i needed to install compression (npm install --save compression) i ended up trying that out and was unsuccessful. do you know why i am running into this problem. Thanks in advanced it means a lot

Comment: @JonathanDasilva sorry, remove `compression(),` my bad

Comment: Or if you want to use compression (which makes your site load quicker) just add `const compression = require("compression")`

Comment: Sorry that I am still having trouble but your suggestion worked with removing the compression() but when I went to localhost:3000 I got "not found". I then realized that I forgot to even put the file that it's suppose to find which is named PC.html which i replaced with the '*' but when i ran the server it gave me a error of "cannot find / " and I'm not sure. sorry that I am not able to figure it out hopefully i have explained it well so you know whats going on

Comment: @JonathanDasilva if you want the root directory to use a certain file, you can use `res.sendFile("./fileName.fileExtention")`

Comment: I tried putting that line of code in multiple places and I still got the same error. The folder is just on my desktop where I just do (cd file path) and node server start the server in my terminal. I was able to find the HTML file before by just putting the (filename.fileextension) so I'm a bit confused why it cant find it anymore. any other suffestion. Again ty for all the help it means a lot